# Why does []=range(0) not raise and exception in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am perplexed as to why these seemingly illegal assignment runs fine in Python 3.

```
[]=range(0)
```

After discovering this completely by accident I started messing around and found that

```
[]=range(1,1)
```

also works, but all of the below raise an exception just as I would expect.

```
[]=range(1)
[]=range(1,2)
[0]=range(0)
[0,1]=range(2)
```

What's going on under the hood here?

Comment: those raise different exception types: too many values to unpack, or can't assign to literal.

Comment: It's like `[a, b] = [1, 2]` -> `a = 1; b = 2` just with an empty list of names of the left. See the duplicate for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know python could do this, but it makes sense.